# How to get the number of pages when paginating comments?

Tags: plugin-development, pagination, comments

I want to display threaded comments via ajax using pagination.

If I use this code to display comments for page 1 how can I know if there is something more to be displayed on page 2? If there is something I would display a link "get more comments" if not there will be no link.

```
$comments =     get_comments(array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'status' => 'approve' 
));
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'page' => 1,
        'per_page' => 10,
        'avatar_size'   => 16,
    ), $comments);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`get_comment_pages_count()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_pages_count)?

```
<?php get_comment_pages_count( $comments, $per_page, $threaded); ?>
```

I'm guessing you're outside the loop, since you're calling `get_comments()`; in that case, you'll need to pass your `$comments` object:

```
$comments =     get_comments(array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'status' => 'approve' 
));
wp_list_comments(array(
        'page' => 1,
        'per_page' => 10,
        'avatar_size'   => 16,
    ), $comments);

$comment_page_count = get_comment_pages_count( $comments );
```

Comment: Works smoothly. Thank you. Just a question why don't I have to use both arguments `$per_page` and `$threaded`. I tested it and it works ok with and without them.

Comment: You don't have to pass the `$per_page` and `$threaded` comments, because `get_comment_pages_count()` will use the default values.

Comment: That is the thing I don't understand. In my sample code above I overwrite the default values...